# Cron работает на 95%

Tags: php, cron

Есть 9 скриптов, которые ежедневно запускаются в 1 минуту (3 скрипта), 2 минуту (3 скрипта), 3 минуту (3 скрипта). Чаще всего запускаются все 9 скриптов, но иногда 1 или даже 2 скрипта не запускаются, по непонятной причине. Есть ли способ в команде крона, чтобы скрипт 100% запустился всегда?

Вот пример того, что мы запускаем через планировщик ISP Manager:

```
/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_1.php        ------> Запуск в 0.01 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_2.php        ------> Запуск в 0.01 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_3.php        ------> Запуск в 0.01 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_4.php        ------> Запуск в 0.02 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_5.php        ------> Запуск в 0.02 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_6.php        ------> Запуск в 0.02 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_7.php        ------> Запуск в 0.03 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_8.php        ------> Запуск в 0.03 ежедневно

/opt/php/7.3/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/u1045989/data/php-bin-php73/php.ini -f /var/www/u1045989/data/www/domen.ru/work/ldate_9.php        ------> Запуск в 0.03 ежедневно
```

Comment: по какому принципу вы определяете, что скрипт не запускается?

Comment: по команде (ps ux)  в isp manager.  Нет процесса 2 из 9, допустим. Все остальные процессы отображаются. Также мы понимаем, что 2 скрипт не создает нужные нам файлы, репорты и т.д. Сегодня 2й, завтра 7й, послезавтра вообще все нормально

Comment: Попробуйте сделать одну точку входа для крона, в ней организуйте очередь. Может Ваш сервер ждёт ожидания завершения задачи. Или сделайте воркеров если есть возможность доступа к серверу

Comment: логи то проверили пхп ?

Comment: в том и дело, что логи php начнет писать, когда конкретный скрипт запустится, мы конечно можем сделать проверку, если не создался лог php, то значит перезапустить задачу крона конкретного скрипта. Скорее всего, проблема в одновременном запуске задач

Comment: ошибки запуска см. в почте пользователя, от которого crond запускает перечисленные вами задаиня.